# My Website Header Image Is Not Resizing On Mobile

Tags: css, header, resize, blogger, responsive

I am using blogger and has a custom template I added a header it works fine but the header is not resizing on mobile template 
My site is https://untoldstoriesofpakistan.blogspot.com

I think this is my css for header

**Header**

```
div#navigation-wrapper {
width: 56%;
float: right;
}
#header {
width: 30%;
background-size: contain;
}
#logo {
text-align:center;
padding:0px 0;
height: 10px;
 background-size: contain;
}
```

**and this is my media css**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    .container {
        width:300px;
    }

    #navigation-wrapper {
        display:none;
    }

    .slicknav_menu {
        display:block;
    }

    #logo img {
        max-width:300px;
        height:auto;
    }

    .post-header h1 a, .post-header h2 a, .post-header h1 {
        font-size:22px;
        letter-spacing:2px;
    }

    .post-image img {
        width:300px;
        height:auto;
    }

    .post-image.audio iframe {
        width:300px;
        height:auto;
    }

    .item-related {
        width:320px;
        margin-bottom:30px;
    }

    .share-box {
        width:46px; 
        height:36px; 
        line-height:36px;
        margin:0 4px;
    }

    .post-pagination .prev-post {
        width:300px;
    }
    .post-pagination .next-post {
        width:300px;
    }

    #respond textarea {
        width:90%;
    }

    .thecomment .author-img {
        display:none;
    }

    #widget-area .widget, #sidebar .widget {
        width:300px;
        margin-right:32px;
        float:left;
        margin-bottom:35px;
    }

    #footer-logo img {
        max-width:300px;
        height:auto;
    }

    #footer-social a i {
        height:28px;
        width:28px;
        line-height:28px;
        margin-right:0;
        font-size:12px;
    }
    #footer-social a {
        margin:0 5px;
    }
    #footer-social a span{
        display:none;
    }

    .wpcf7 textarea {
        width:94%;
    }

    .sp-grid li {
        width:320px;
    }
    .sp-grid li:nth-child(3n+3) {
        margin-right:0;
    }
    .sp-grid li:nth-child(2n+2) {
        margin-right:0;
    }

    .container.sp_sidebar #main {
        width:300px;
        margin-right:0;
    }
    .container.sp_sidebar #sidebar {
        width:300px;
    }

        .container.sp_sidebar #sidebar .widget {
            width:300px;
        }

    .container.sp_sidebar .item-related {
        width:300px;
        margin-bottom:30px;
    }


    .col-md-6.site-top-menu-right.text-right {
    display: none;
    }





    div#sidebar-narrow {
    display: none;
    }

    div#main-part {
    float: left;
    width: 310px;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Any HTML in there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change header image size. Search your code for

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px){
  #logo img {
     max-width: 480px;
        height: auto;
     }
  }

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #logo img {
        max-width: 300px;
        height: auto;
     }
  }

img#Header1_headerimg {
      width: 180px;
      height: 55px;
      float: left;
 }
```

and replace it with

```
img#Header1_headerimg {
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: does i have to change the whole media css from        
@ media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px){
  #logo img {
     max-width: 480px;
        height: auto;
     }
  }

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #logo img {
        max-width: 300px;
        height: auto;
     }
  }

img#Header1_headerimg {
      width: 180px;
      height: 55px;
      float: left;
 }

to 

img#Header1_headerimg {
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

Comment: No, delete what inside the media query and use the bottom code outside media.

Comment: Cant find that code plz explain in detail and in simpler words i will be very thankful to you all the time

Comment: Go to your code. click in any where. click CTRL+F and search for `#logo img` delete it and its inside code. repeat twice. then search for `img#Header1_headerimg` and change the width to auto.

Answer (score 0):

**Change the code in css with this one :**

```
#logo img { 
    max-width: 10em;
    height: auto;
}
```